# BSOD on Windows 7 even on a fresh install

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, motherboard, bsod

I had Windows 7 installed and was receving BSOD after BSOD every hour or so.

- Motherboard: ASRock X79 Extreme6
- Memory: 64GB Corsair DDR3 PC2133 (8x8GB)
- Graphics Card: AMD R9 270X (4GB)
- Processor: Intel Core i7 4930K 3.40GHz
- CPU Cooler: Corsair H100i
- PSU: Corsair RM 750W

I've done the following checks:

- sfc /scannow [Completed, No Errors]
- chkdsk /f /r [Completed, No Errors]
- Windows Memory Diagnostics [Completed, No Errors]
- Memtest 86+ [Completed, No Errors]
- IntelBurnTest (CPU Stress Test) [Completed, No BSOD or overheating]
- FurMark (GPU Stress Test) [Completed, No BSOD or overheating]

#### Minidumps: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vdr6gampskjrnc8/AABVazZZsHAkEjV_rqxwRBD6a?dl=0

#### Picture of Minidumps in BlueScreenView:

[image]

I haven't installed ANYTHING yet on this fresh install and it's still crashing :/

What should I do?

Comment: I'm currently on a mac with no hope of opening a dump file quickly.. what was the BSOD error message? (LOOKS_LIKE_THIS)

Comment: @Jonah Sorry, checkout: http://i.imgur.com/x5BcDEq.png it has all of them visible

Comment: How long did you run Memtest for? Also, is this before or after you've loaded drivers for the peripherals? Have you performed a hardware elimination (remove all but one stick of memory, remove all extraneous hardware, remove everything you can boot without, then add back one at a time)?

Comment: @music2myear I ran MemTest86+ for 24 hours, I ran Windows Memory Diagnostics for 18 hours. I've not installed any drivers for peripherals yet but I did for the first 8 minidumps, everything was installed :/ I've got 4 sticks of memory in atm, I'm gonna switch it over if it crashes again to see if it is the memory.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm going to say it's either a bad connection, a cooling issue, or memory. Because you've tried without drivers and it still crashes, that pretty much eliminates a software problem.

Comment: Oh, and your CPU and GPU testing seems to eliminate a cooling issue as the culprit. I forgot to remove that from the list of possibilities.

Comment: @music2myear my temperatures look fine, cpu is 28*C and the cores range from 18*C to 28*C. GPU is 36*C and harddrives are 24-30*C, I've unplugged everything inside and replugged it once. I'll try again though after/if it crashes again

Comment: Just so you know; your problem isn't a driver or software problem based on the provided information so don't reinstall windows it won't help

Comment: @Ramhound I've re-installed 3 times including using up to date pre-activated versions just to see if it was something to do with my old windows 7 disc.

Comment: I could have told you it didn't onve you reinstall an os and the same problems happens then it's either a bad driver or a hardware problem

Comment: I posted on SevenForums and they wouldn't help me because I had re-installed with a pre-activated one even though I have proof that I own Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: is the Corsair RAM supported by the motherboard?

Answer (score 4):

This is a hardware issue, 
First thing first:

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64 has a RAM limit to 16GB max, while the Pro x64 & Ultimate x64 versions have a limitation of 192GB of RAM.
- IF you overclocked your CPU, then, UNDO the changes.
- USE ONLY 8GB RAM.
- IF the PCIe slots are used, then unplug them all.
- UNPLUG any device that is connected to the computer.

NOW, connect the monitor, keyboard and mouse. 
Turn on your computer and check your system, and try to use it long enough to determine if the BSOD will appear or not. IF everything looks good, then turn it off, and plug the second RAM chip and turn it on and check. Do the same process for all cards and devices until you hit the Jackpot !

Answer (score 1):

Random BSoD's from different random sources is almost always RAM, especially on a newly built system.

You should be running Memetest86+ for DAYS to test RAM, like 48-72 hours straight. Especially when we're talking about 64GB of RAM.

My advice for now, take out all but a single 8GB stick and test it.  Repeat until all sticks have been tested, and any that show problems need to be replaced. If when using them singly errors don't show up, then start testing them with additional sticks added (one at a time) until the problem comes back.

If it only fails when you have more than one stick in, or a specific amount of sticks (regardless of which ones you use), then it may be a timing issue, which if it isn't fixed by a BIOS update on your motherboard, then it most likely means the RAM sticks are having timing issues between them and in that case, they just suck and you should change RAM brands. ;)

Comment: I've taken 4 sticks of RAM out seeing if it still crashes, I'll test the ram sticks like you said in a slightly different order. I've already updated the BIOS (successfully) to try and fix the BSOD issue

Comment: Oh, and to be thorough you have to test EACH stick of RAM in EACH slot too. :) Welcome to the life of IT.

Comment: @music2myear haha, yeah I know. It's managed to stay up for 52mins so far, which is one of the longest it's been on for... if it is still up when it reaches a 2 hour uptime I'll switch all 4 sticks of ram for the other 4 and test the second 32gb batch before moving back onto the first 4 sticks of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Your DUMPS says TCP/IP Driver Error.

1. Boot to save mode
2. Remove Network Adapter driver (NIC Model) (My Computer -> Properties->Device Driver TAB)
3. Restart windows, and have it detect and install OEM driver.

After a fresh install, suggested driver installations are:
1. Chipset driver, then reboot.
2. NIC Driver 
3. Windows Updates
4. Audio/Video driver
5. remaining device drivers.

Reboot as necessary after each driver installation.

Comment: I've tried that one already, including trying the latest NIC driver from Broadcom.

Answer (score 0):

As the others say, certainly a hardware issue.  However, it looks like you have done your due diligence regarding disk and memory checks, and it sounds like your mobo is a bit funky.  You've helped to rule out the RAM, the CPU, the disk and the software.  Unfortunately the only reasonable way to test the mobo is to swap it out; fortunately, they are one of the cheapest components :).

I say this from personal experience, troubleshooting my old problematic PC that simply wouldn't behave after troubleshooting and/or replacing everything else.  It experienced the same issues you describe.  Swapping out the mobo fixed everything.